# can i pass model column as a property

Tags: qml

```
ListView {
 model: dataModel
    delegate: Column {
        id: delegate
        Row {
            Repeater {
                model: 1
                ItemDelegate {
                    id:columnDelegate
                   text:name
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

instead of text:name can i pass model column name as a property,have any way to assign model column name dynamically..?

```
    ListView {
         property var columnName //pass column name as property
         model: dataModel
            delegate: Column {
                id: delegate
                Row {
                    Repeater {
                        model: 1
                        ItemDelegate {
                            id:columnDelegate
                           text:columnName //assign property as column name here
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
        }
```

something like this is possible?have any way to solve this problem?
can i pass model column names as an array?

Comment: The way QML uses the models is with roles. You should use `modelData.<role>` and from your model, you should return different data based on the role (assuming you are implementing a `QAbstractItemModel`)

Comment: If you wish to use array data for the `text` source, have a look at looping through an array, to assign the `text`, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp alternatively check out the documentation for models here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using array data, and wish to use this as your `model` within a `repeater`, you can do the following:

```
Column {
    Repeater {
    model: ["apples", "oranges", "pears"]
    text: modelData
    }
}
```

taken from [Repeater QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html)

Should you have more in depth data, such as JSON, from i.e a web server, you also can look at things such as

```
property var arrayData: {apples: {type: "fruit", colour: "green"}, oranges: {type: "fruit", colour: "orange"}, pears: {type: "fruit", colour: "green"}}

model: Object.keys(arrayData) //the 'key' (apples/oranges/pears)

text: arrayData.type // all would be 'fruit' in this example
detailText: arrayData.colour // moreso is you are using a `SimpleRow` to display your data`, but an example of usage
```

If your data will be more details objects, this is great for accessing properties, alternatively, if it's static like the first example, or a simple array. perfect!

I would suggest you take a look at [Models and Views in QtQuick](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html) for other examples to help you!

Hope it helps!